Schedule in Laravel 11
We are facing an issue with Laravel scheduled tasks using the call method in Kernel.php not executing as expected in development mode on Windows. When running php artisan schedule:work, it only displays "No scheduled commands are ready to run," even though a simple task has been added.
Here’s the minimal example we’re using in Kernel.php:
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) { $schedule->call(function () {Log::info("Hello world"); })->everyMinute(); }

We expected to see "Hello world" appear in the log file (storage/logs/laravel.log), but it doesn’t.
Steps we’ve already tried:

Verifying the syntax of the Kernel.php file.

Running the appropriate Artisan commands: php artisan schedule:run and php artisan schedule:work.

Checking the permissions on the log file.


Despite these attempts, the scheduled task is not working. Does anyone have suggestions to resolve this?

In Laravel 11, schedule definitions have been moved to routes/console.php

Why is this tagged with Laravel 4, 5, and 8? Also, which parts of https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scheduling did you apply?

Here’s an updated version with at least 15 characters:
I am currently developing a project in Laravel 11 for my Master’s degree. I tagged Laravel 4, 5, and 8 in my question to get help from a broader range of Laravel developers. I’m a beginner and just learned that schedule definitions have been moved from Kernel.php in Laravel 11. Could someone confirm this and explain where the schedules should now be defined? I’ve already reviewed the documentation but need some clarification.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, why not use the official documentation to check where the code should be placed?

Thank you for your responses! I managed to resolve the issue by moving the scheduled task to routes/console.php as suggested.

Nico Haase I am a begginer and Thank you !

Great that you solved it. We don't have anything against beginners, but you should probably take the [tour] and check [ask] to get the most out of this site.
